# android termux busybox do not let me run commands

Tags: applications, termux

Anyone knows why when I try to run a command on termux like nc busybox try to run the command instead netcat the same happens when i try to run tar busybox gets in the way ?

Answer (score 1):

Because Termux installs BusyBox in its bootstrap package, to avoid bloating too much.

Full-functional utilies like Core Utilities or netcat can be installed with the bundled package manager `apt`. For example

```
apt install coreutils inetutils netcat tar gzip #(and many more ...)
```

Comment: But ive imstalled netcat already same happens i can only run netcat with netcat vommand and not with the nc command cause busybox gets in the way, i tjink its metasploit i recently installed that ruined my termux